# Why do I need to access the base class constructor with super()?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Why do I need to reference the base class' constructor in the subclass? I seem to get the same result either way.

```
class Animal {
    constructor(age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}

class Mammal extends Animal {}

let lion = new Mammal(3);
lion.age //=> 3
```

as opposed to

```
class Mammal extends Animal {
    constructor(){
        super(3)
    }
}

let lion = new Mammal();
lion.age //=> 3
```

Comment: In general in OOP: if you *don't* override a method in a child class, the parent's implementation will be used. That's basic inheritance and `extend`ing a class wouldn't make much sense otherwise. `super()` is necessary when you *do* override a parent's method and still want to call said parent's implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't provide an explicit constructor, in a subclass<sup>1</sup> the JavaScript engine will generate one for you that looks like this:

```
constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
}
```

That's what's going on in your first example. So this:

```
class Mammal extends Animal {
}
```

is the same as this:

```
class Mammal extends Animal {
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
    }
}
```

...it's just that the second is explicit, whereas the first is using the constructor inserted into the class for you by the JavaScript engine.

This is defined in Step 10 of [§14.5.14: *Runtime Semantics: ClassDefinitionEvaluation*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-runtime-semantics-classdefinitionevaluation):

> 10. If *constructor* is empty, then
>
>     - If *ClassHeritage*<sub>opt</sub> is present, then
>
>       - Let *constructor* be the result of parsing the source text
>
>         ```
>         constructor(... args){ super (...args);}
>         ```
>
>         using the syntactic grammar with the goal symbol *MethodDefinition*.
>     - Else,
>
>       - Let *constructor* be the result of parsing the source text
>
>         ```
>         constructor( ){ }
>         ```
>
>         using the syntactic grammar with the goal symbol *MethodDefinition*.

---

<sup>1</sup> If it's not a subclass, as you can see above, it's just `constructor() { }`.

Comment: In a nutshell, in the first case, the JavaScript engine provides me with an implicit `constructor(...args) { super(...args) }` behind the scenes, correct?

Comment: @SvetanDimoff: Exactly.

Comment: I'm assuming specifying one myself is the better practice here?

Comment: @SvetanDimoff: That's a matter of style, it's up to you. For me, an implicit constructor is fine; the rules are quite simple and easily learned. But others may feel that being explicit is preferred. (In *general*, I tend toward explicitness, but for this I'm a good 75/25 in favor of implicit on the basis that less code is good. But it's a matter of opinion.)